# Find and replace in a specific column

Tags: python, perl, sed, awk, vi

I have a file like this:

```
Name Position Letter String
Bla 123 A ..B.,,,.C..
Bla 123 B ..a.,,,.C..
Bla 123 C ..b.,,,.A..
```

I would like to replace the `.` and `,` with Letter (in the first line it's `A`)

The end product:

```
Name Position Letter String
Bla 123 A AABAAAAACAA
Bla 123 B BBaBBBBBCBB
Bla 123 C CCbCCCCCACC
```

The awk thinking is replace character in column 4 with "the" character in column 3.
I think awk should be the correct tool for this but I´m stuck with replacing character in string.

`sed s/\(^.\{4\}\)./\\{3\}/` didn't work and I think sed may be the wrong tool.

Awk/sed/python/perl/vi solutions welcomed.

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/\.|,/, $3, $4); print}' inputfile`

Comment: That's what I was looking for! correct usage of the gsub command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
perl -pale '$F[3]=~s/[.,]/$F[2]/g;$_=join" ",@F' file
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/g0Atv)

Comment: +1, I wonder if this counts as "morbidly obese" for a perl script...

Comment: Obese and ugly, but did the work. Thanks.

Comment: `awk 'a=$3{gsub(/\.|\,/, a); print }' file`

Comment: Great, Dennis Williamson improved this by only replacing characters in column 4, this would replace . and , in all columns.

Answer (score 3):

solution without using `regular expressions`:

```
   with open('in.txt') as f:
        for x in f:
            x=x.rstrip().split()
            x[-1]=x[-1].replace('.',x[-2])
            x[-1]=x[-1].replace(',',x[-2])
            print(" ".join(x))

    Name Position Letter String
    Bla 123 A AABAAAAACAA
    Bla 123 B BBaBBBBBCBB
    Bla 123 C CCbCCCCCACC
```

Comment: Python, in case someone doesn't recognize it.